# Transform user settings with slowCheetah

Tags: c#, .net, settings, slowcheetah

I am trying you change my default user configuration according to the build profile with slowCheetah, however I am not able to find the right way to use it

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="MyApp.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <MyApp.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Url" serializeAs="String">
                <value>
                    something
                </value>
            </setting>
        </MyApp.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

I have been trying

```
<!-- &amp it's an & escaped in xml-->
<add key="MyApp.Properties.Settings.Url" value="www.google.com" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You want to add a line inside `<MyApp.Properties.Settings>`?

Comment: I want to substitute a value with a default one, to generate a correct setup for deployment

Comment: But in your configuration file you don't have a `MyApp.Properties.Settings.GigaSpaceLocator` so there is nothing to replace

Comment: that was a copy paste error. Look the updated question, the setting is called Url

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I get it right, you have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="MyApp.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <MyApp.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Url" serializeAs="String">
                <value>
                    something
                </value>
            </setting>
        </MyApp.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

And you want to transform it to:

(replace `<value>something</value>` with `<value>www.google.com</value>`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="MyApp.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <MyApp.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Url" serializeAs="String">
                <value>
                    www.google.com
                </value>
            </setting>
        </MyApp.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

The easiest way to do this is to have the following text in your transformation file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <userSettings>
        <MyApp.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Url" serializeAs="String">
                <value xdt:Transform="Replace">
                    www.google.com
                </value>
            </setting>
        </MyApp.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

It replaces (`<value xdt:Transform="Replace">`) your `<value></value>` with the text you want.

Or if you want to select the section to replace with the `name="Url"` attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <userSettings>
        <MyApp.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Url" serializeAs="String" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
                <value>
                    www.google.com
                </value>
            </setting>
        </MyApp.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

We do the same action here (replace: `xdt:Transform="Replace"`) but we reach the value to change by matching an attribute: `xdt:Locator="Match(name)"`

Comment: I have tested both and they worked but maybe with the full file it doesn't!